# Npm crashing error when trying to deploy build

Tags: javascript, heroku

I am working on a Discord Bot and trying to host it off of Heroku. I ran into this particular error while going through this process and I am  unsure how to proceed.

I am unsure what to try here or what these errors mean. This shows up in the Heroku logs for my app.

[image]

I am just trying to use Heroku to host my bot but this am running into this issue while attempting to do this.

Comment: check the compatible version

Comment: Have you checked dubug_log file ?

Comment: Where/How can I access the debug_log file at?

Comment: Please paste the logs as text instead of as an image.